# How to run a script as a service in UBUNTU

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu

I have a script which normally i run using ./myscript.sh(contain java run command) on linux. Now i want to make it as a service so it run automatically after machine restart and if i want to stop and start again simply find the process and kill and start it again from command line.

What i find with quick google search is to place the script in /etc/init.d directory but confusing with one thing that command inside this script using other certificate files which i normally place on same level where this script is place. Do i need to move all others file along with this script under /etc/init.d or is there any better way that i simply mention the path of this script in some file?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to [write systemd service file](http://patrakov.blogspot.co.uk/2011/01/writing-systemd-service-files.html).

Simplest script looks like this:

```
[Unit]
Description=Virtual Distributed Ethernet

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/YOUR_SCRIPT

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Also you need: `systemctl daemon-reload` after creating new service.

Comment: Do not forget to enable the service for it to run on startup! `systemctl enable YOUR_SERVICE.service`, also, don't forget giving the script execution permission

Comment: is stopping supported using such script ?

Comment: Answer on this link provides good details on it: https://askubuntu.com/questions/919054/how-do-i-run-a-single-command-at-startup-using-systemd